# WPF DataGridColumnHeader Elements don't get focus on first click

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

I have a terrible problem with WPF DataGrid!I've put a `TextBox` inside a `DataGridColumnHeader`,and  changed the `KeyBoardLanguage` on `TextBox_GotFocus`.
Here's my style for `DataGridColumnHeader`:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridSelectorColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" >
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox  xamlservices:GotFocusBehavior.GotFocus="{Binding TextBoxGotFocusCommand}"
                          xamlservices:GotFocusBehavior.GotFocusParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And:

```
  public ICommand TextBoxGotFocusCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand<TextBox>(OnTextBoxGotFocus); }
    }
  TextBox txtSearch;
  private void OnTextBoxGotFocus(TextBox sender)
  {
     txtSearch = sender;
     if (...)
     {
       CultureInfo lanq = new CultureInfo("en-us", false);
       InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(txtSearch, lanq);
     }
  }
```

The problem is that the language get changed when i click on the `Textbox`,the click some where else and back to the `TextBox`!It doesn't change language on first click.
Any idea would be appreciated.